# Add own field to Admin Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I would like make log system for many Entity. For example i have Entity: Blog, Page and News. They are admin class:

```
class (Blog|Page|News/)Admin.php
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('title', null, array())
                ->add('body', null, array())
            ->end();
    }
}
```

I would like also Entity Log. This has fields: log, description and date. I would like add field description to Blog, Page and News:

```
class (Blog|Page|News)Admin.php
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('title', null, array())
                ->add('body', null, array())
                ->add('description', 'text', array())
            ->end();
    }
}
```

but this return error - this field not exist in Entity (Blog|Page|News). I can add setDescription, getDescription etc to Entity, but this is wrong way if i have a lot of entity to logging and i will have all logs in one table (Entity Log), not in all Entities - (Blog|Page|News). I use preUpdate to save this data to table Log, but i dont know how i can add field description from Entity Log to these Entities. I can also make relation but this is also wrong way.
Maybe i should use extends class? But how?

Answer (score 5):

You can add your field in sonata admin ..

It's right way to add optional filed in sonata admin form

```
     $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('title', null, array('mapped'=>false))
            ->add('body', null, array())
            ->add('description', 'text', array())
        ->end();
```

Add **'mapped'=>false** in third argument

Comment: you have to spécify the type now -> like this : ->add('title', 'text', array('mapped'=>false))

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't optional fields have 'required' set to false

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper){
//
->add('title', 'text', array('mapped'=>false, 'required'=> false))
//
}
```